# wordpress registration page - create a style sheet for it

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to style the registration page background in wordpress. I put some styles into my child-theme but they weren't picked up  - think because the page isn't pulling in my style.css which I am doing this way in my functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
```

Ideally I don't want to edit the login.css in the admin section.

How do i get my own style sheet to be loaded for the registration page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

There's also ways to edit the logo and so forth, without having to resolve to CSS. Read more here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form